# How to generate merit list from exam results in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite database in Android . I have a table called tstResult in my database.

```
 AI  SubID  StudID  StudName  TotalMarks  ObtainedMarks
--------------------------------------------------------
 1  |   1  |   1  |  Jakir   |    100    |    90
 2  |   1  |   2  |  Rubel   |    100    |    75
 3  |   1  |   3  |  Ruhul   |    100    |    82
 4  |   1  |   4  |  Beauty  |    100    |    82
 5  |   1  |   5  |  Bulbul  |    100    |    96
 6  |   1  |   6  |  Ripon   |    100    |    82
 7  |   1  |   7  |  Aador   |    100    |    76
 8  |   1  |   8  |  Jibon   |    100    |    80
 9  |   1  |   9  |  Rahaat  |    100    |    82
```

Now I want a SELECT query that generate a merit list according to the Obtained Marks. In this query obtained marks "96" will be the top in the merit list and all the "82" marks will be placed one after another in the merit list. Something like this:

```
 StudID  StudName  TotalMarks  ObtainedMarks Merit List
 ----------------------------------------------------------
 |   5  |  Bulbul  |    100    |     96     |   1
 |   1  |  Jakir   |    100    |     90     |   2
 |   9  |  Rahaat  |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   3  |  Ruhul   |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   4  |  Beauty  |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   6  |  Ripon   |    100    |     82     |   3
 |   8  |  Jibon   |    100    |     80     |   4
 |   7  |  Aador   |    100    |     76     |   5
 |   2  |  Rubel   |    100    |     75     |   6
```

How can I do this ? Any advice is of great help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of distinctly greater obtained numbers (+1)

```
SELECT res.StudId
    , res.StudName
    , res.TotalMarks
    , res.ObtainedMarks
    , (
        SELECT 1+COUNT(DISTINCT obtainedMarks) 
        FROM tstResult greater 
        WHERE greater.ObtainedMarks > res.ObtainedMarks
    ) MeritList
 FROM tstResult res
 ORDER BY res.ObtainedMarks DESC
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2769a/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

`SELECT * FROM tstResult ORDER BY ObtainedMarks DESC`

Which will give you the result in sorted order by Obtained Marks.